# Javascript Variable Not Changing Value With Html Content Changing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that im trying to make a variable that changes if the price of the product changes
hers the code:

```
<h3 class="single-price"><span class="after currency-value"><span class="value">5000</span></h3>

var price_aft = document.querySelector("#app > main > div > div > div.container > div > div.product-details > div.product-section.price-section > h3 > span.after.currency-value > span.value").textContent
```

when the price changes the variable value does not change? can someone help me please! thank you.

Comment: When you assign the textContent to a variable that is a snapshot of the value at the time of the assignment, not a live view of the text content of the DOM.

Comment: Are you sure you understand how that code works? Because that querySelector statement is going to read the value when it’s called once. How did you expect it to update the variable and run automatically on its own when some value changes on dom? Your question is confusing and it’s not even clear how that value on document is going to change. Because that’s the event that should trigger the action to update the variable and there is no way to show you if that’s all you have to share. Unless you use Observable but that’s another story maybe too big for your scenario

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You need to tell an intent behind what you write here.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is malformed. So, I'm not sure you mean:

A:

```html
<h3 class="single-price">
  <span class="after currency-value">
    <span class="value">5000</span>
  </span>
</h3>
```

or B:

```html
<h3 class="single-price">
  <span class="after currency-value"></span>
  <span class="value">5000</span>
</h3>
```

So, I went with option A:

```js
let selector = ".single-price .after .value";
let priceAft = document.querySelector(selector);
console.log(priceAft.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h3 class="single-price">
  <span class="after currency-value">
    <span class="value">5000</span>
  </span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW, that's an enormous selector chain,

first of all, make sure your selector is correct, you can remove .textContent from the end of your js code and see if querySelector can find your element (use console.log to see what is stored in your variable)

then
if the variable has undefined value, your selector is wrong
if the element was selected correctly, try out innerText instead of textContent and let me know of the result

Answer (score 0):

```js
  // select span
  var target = document.getElementById('value');
var currValue = '';

// create observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log("event trigger " + mutation.target.id);
  });
});

// pass what to listen
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};

// pass span node and config
observer.observe(target, config);

// simulate the Change of the text value of span
function onValueChange() {
  currValue = target.textContent;
  console.log(currValue);
}

setTimeout(onValueChange, 2000);
```

```html
<h3 class="single-price"><span class="after currency-value"><span id="value" class="value">5000</span></h3>
```